# phone gap map issue for android

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

i am just trying to get practiced with phone gap for android devices. I found an map based app [here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494764/PhoneGap%20Geolocation%20Sample%20Application)

Following is the javascript i tried to run

```
<html>
     <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; user-scalable=no" />
          <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
          <title>Beer Me</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
          <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/phonegap.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
               function loader() 
               {
                    var state = document.readyState;
                    if (state == 'loaded' || state == 'complete') 
                    {
                         run();
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                         if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Browzr') > -1) 
                         {
                              setTimeout(run, 250);
                         } 
                         else 
                         {
                              document.addEventListener('deviceready',run,false);
                         }
                    }
               }
               function run() 
               {
                    var win = function(position) {                          // Grab coordinates object from the Position object passed into success callback.
                         var coords = position.coords;
                         var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + coords.latitude + "," + coords.longitude + "&zoom=13&size=320x480&maptype=roadmap&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sensor=true";
                         document.getElementById('map').setAttribute('src',url);
                    };
                    var fail = function(e) 
                    {
                         alert('Can\'t retrieve position.\nError: ' + e);
                    };
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(win, fail);
               } 
          </script>
     </head>
     <body onload="loader();">
          <img id="map" />
     </body>
</html>
```

when i run in the android device it shows an alert box that `Can\'t retrieve position`.
The function for Position is not been called. How to get the position of a place in phone gap javascript, please help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are talking about that exact code, it looks like it wants a key for google maps. That tutorial is a year old which is ancient in google map time.

If you are willing to move to Google Maps JavaScript v3 (non-static - no key, much more powerful and interesting to use than static maps), here's a gettting-started google map [route finder tutorial](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4part1). It's also from the phonegap wiki pages, see [android tutorials](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501397/Tutorials), scroll down to the one titled [jQuery Google Maps Plugin for Google Maps v3: Route Finder App](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4part1).